# Custom fields on custom object mapped to custom field on standard object

Tags: map

I have created a custom object "CustomLead" in that i am having custom field "companyName". I need to map this field to Account Std object, in Account Std Object i have created acc_name. How to map this field.

Comment: Are you trying to build a logic equivalent to lead conversion?

Comment: yes, exactly that what we need. It must do the same logic equivalent to lead conversion. In this customlead field we have created a new custom button "Convert", once we click convert it must create a account.contact & opportunity.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just add a custom field to Leads?

Comment: Are you using a VF page for your custom "Convert" button? If so you can map those fields in your controller when creating the account.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Lavanya Sanathkumar,

There are two approaches here. 1st is Workflow and 2nd is trigger.

1st : For Workflow, you will need to have a have a relation between Account and CustomLead Object. Then you can create a workflow for "EveryTime record is created or updated" for Custom Lead Object. And keep an action of "Field Update". This field update action will update the provide Account field.

2nd : For Trigger, you will need to have a relation between Account and Custom Lead Object. Here you will need to have trigger on CustomLead Object for event of AfterInsert, AfterUpdate and AfterDelete. So whenever you are performing DML on CustomLead there will be logic for updating the related Account record with "companyName" field.

Thanks